# Using Kohana in File outside Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

Here's the situation:

I have a catch-all on my domain email (so *@domain.com) redirecting to a piping script located at /home/domain/scripts/piper.php.  This piper script is not within the Kohana ORM, but all of my other files are.  I want to try to use Kohana inside this piper.php file.

I have tried (unsuccessfully) all of the following:

**Including Kohana**

I couldn't figure out what needed to be included, and more importantly how to override the url variable that Kohana uses to determine the right controller.  Also, this is a catch-all piper, so it isn't using HTTP (to my knowledge), so much as executing a command.

**Piping**

I tried piping to the following:

```
/home/domain/public_html/index.php --uri="piper"
```

But cPanel makes this impossible, as you can only specify the destination script, and not the proper flags and such (unless I am missing something).

**PHP exec()**

I tried using the following line:

```
exec("php /home/domain/public_html/index.php --uri=\"/piper\"")
```

I was hoping that the stdin data would be maintained across the exec() command, but I could never get it to recognize the uri command, though I can run this on my localhost and it works just fine.

I was using http://www.coderelic.com/2011/10/creating-cron-jobs-in-kohana-3-x-is-a-piece-of-cake/ as a reference, but can't get anything to work.

I'm happy with either one of these solutions such that I can see an incoming email, parse it, then send emails based on the parameters.

Let me know if you need more information!  I'm le stumped.

Comment: On your php exec make sure to include the full path to php. If you dont know it, go to a command line and type "which php". I use something similar in a cron job. Example: /usr/bin/php /path/to/kohana/index.php --uri="/apn/index?task=fetch"

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to:

1. modify your `piper.php` script to be a valid PHP class;
2. place it in `/application/classes/` folder;

Kohana will automatically load your class file (like `include`) during initialization.

Then you can use your `piper` class as usual class by `$piper = new Piper; ...`.

**UPD**

You have to serve your emails trough Kohana.

Create controller, for example `pipe` (route it with `/pipe` URL):

```
public function action_pipe() {

    $pipe = new Pipe; // This creates new Pipe object (your emails serving class)

    $pipe->serve(); // Sserve emails within `serve()` method of Pipe class

}
```

Comment: Emails are piped to a script that is _outside_ Kohana.  This means I need to somehow initialize Kohana.  If I make my piper a class (which I have a controller called piper, btw) then I can't simply include it.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, but this would require me to pipe my emails (as they come in) to a url (domain.com/pipe), right?  I'm not sure how to do that in cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

`/home/domain/public_html/index.php --uri="piper"` would be a valid way to do it. If your host sucks and doesn't let you specify that, put it into a bash script instead and reference that.

If you are on any recent version of kohana (3.2 or 3.3), a better way to do this would be to use Minion to run the command line task. This is what Minion was designed for.

Comment: I tried creating a shell script, but it seems that the `--uri` flag doesn't stick.  I'm not sure why, but unless I am typing in the command into the shell, that flag doesn't stick.  So calling it from using `exec()` or calling a shell script using `shell_exec()` also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Although admittedly, I'm not sure if these other answers are correct because I can't figure out how to reproduce the results.

What ended up working for my situation was to create a `Controller_Piper` class that is called in the `/home/domain/scripts/piper.php`.  What I did was to copy the code from `/home/domain/public_html/index.php` and changed the following:

```
echo Request::factory("/piper")
->execute()
->send_headers(TRUE)
->body();
```

This loads the `piper` controller and executes everything very nicely.  Not sure if it's the cleanest, but it does work.

Comment: This seems like a fine solution considering the bad hosting you seem to have :)